# How to check where an app is sending data over internet on Android?

Tags: adb

How to check where an app is sending data and making requests over the internet on Android?

Is this possible with ADB or something else?

I want to monitor an app for data it is sending over the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [tPacketCapture](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.co.taosoftware.android.packetcapture) to route your traffic through a local VPN.

The app will then write a log which you can open with [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/) on your desktop and analyze data flow.

It won't allow you to see which app sent which packet, but this is as good as it gets without root. Although there is a Pro version available which allows you to filter out applications.

Comment: That sounds good. I'll try that.

Comment: Hey Oliver, this method works great... for HTTP traffic. Is there any way to sniff HTTPS traffic? Maybe just the sent data?

Comment: How to obtain this log from a non-rooted device??

Answer (score 1):

No-Root firewall does the same. The advantage is that it is all displayed in a GUI-interface. To function, it creates a VPN(disadvantage of this is that you can't use your own VPN at the same time of course). Then it lists the apps that want's to access a certain IP address over a certain port, and you can decide if you want to allow or disallow in the ip or range over WIFI or mobile.

This works great for dedicated apps, but for some system apps this is tricky, because they are displayed bundeld. Also there are requests for certain IP address of '...cloudfront..' servers. These servers are hosting servers that change continously and you will never know who is behind it and what data is send to it.

And example of a bundled app from android that I have is:
"*Android System, Atci_service, com.mediatek, com.mediatek.batterywarning, com.mediatek.voiceextension, Common Data Service, FloatWindow, FotaProvider, Fused Location, Input Devices, Key Chain, MiraVision, MMITest, Mobile anti-theft, MTK Thermal Manager, Permission Control, Phone, Schedule power on & off, Settings Storage, Setting, SmartcardService, UpgradeSys, Voice Unlock*"

Comment: because of this answer my account is banned from adding other answers to stackoverflow?... Why?

Comment: Done with Stack. Your system of rating members does not help contributors, but even supports getting more leechers.